# ¿Cómo comparar dos fechas y hacer un conteo?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Como puedo comparar dos fechas de una misma tabla, y obtener la cantidad de días  entre mi FechaSalida y FechaLlegada?

Estoy utilizando lo siguiente:

```
Declare @NumOperador int, @FechaDesde datetime, @FechaHasta datetime, @cveJornada int
set @FechaDesde='2017-07-01 00:00:00.000'
set @FechaHasta='2017-07-20 00:00:00.000'
set @NumOperador=452127
set @cveJornada=1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpDes') Is Not Null DROP TABLE #tmpDes

Select distinct cc.NumOperador,
  CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha) Fecha,
  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, cc.jornada_ini, CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha)) % j.DiasTotal)<j.DiasLabores THEN 'Dia Labor' END AS DiaTrabajado,
  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, cc.jornada_ini, CONVERT(DATE,X.Fecha)) % j.DiasTotal)>=j.DiasLabores THEN 'Dia Descanso'  END AS DiaDescansado,
  CONVERT(DATE,Y.Llegada) Llegada,
  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, cc.jornada_ini, CONVERT(DATE,Y.Llegada)) % j.DiasTotal)<j.DiasLabores THEN 'Dia Labor' END AS DiaTrabajadoLlegada,
  CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY, cc.jornada_ini, CONVERT(DATE,Y.Llegada)) % j.DiasTotal)>=j.DiasLabores THEN 'Dia Descanso'  END AS DiaDescansadoLlegada
  into #tmpDes
FROM CopCalendario CC
INNER JOIN trfDespacho D on D.numOperador=cc.NumOperador
INNER JOIN trkJornada J on j.cveJornada=cc.TipoJornada
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                  (D.FechaSalida)) x(Fecha)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
                  (D.FechaLlegada)) y(Llegada)
WHERE (CC.NumOperador= @NumOperador or @NumOperador=0)
and D.FechaSalida >=@FechaDesde and D.FechaSalida <=@FechaHasta+1
and D.FechaSalida is not null 
select* from #tmpDes
```

[image: Resultado]

Muestro la tabla en donde envío los registros, quiero comparar la FechaSalida y FechaLlegada, para hacer un conteo de las fechas que sería 8 fechas sin duplicarse.

Comment: No entender, cual es la finalidad de que uses `APPLY`. En el resultado (imagen) que muestras la columna `Fecha` contiene `FechaSalida` y `Llegada` contiene `FechaLlegada`, entonces, la cantidad de días entre la `FechaSalida` y `FechaLlegada`, con valor `0` serían 6 registros y con valor `1` serían 1 registros (**Según la imagen**). Podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/92875/edit) e indicarnos cual sería el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas caballero, para poder saber la diferencia que hay entre dos fechas se puede hacer con la propiedad DateDiff,  que en su primer argumento recibe la parte de la fecha que quieres comparar, en tu caso entiendo que seria "D" de day, dias en ingles, y como segundo y tercer argumento las dos fechas que quieres comparar, puedes guardar ese resultado en una variable y luego comparas si es igual a 8.
Ejemplo:

```
Declare @diferencia int

Set diferencia  = DATEDiFF(day, Fecha, Llegada)
```

Link : [DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)