# Calcular el número de días entre dos fechas (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, script

tengo el siguiente script:

```
SELECT        T1.ArrivalDate AS Llegada, T1.DepartureDate AS Salida, T3.AccountNo AS Folio, T6.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T7.Name AS Tarifa, 
                         T1.ID_SrcBusiness
FROM            obooGuest AS T1 INNER JOIN
                         obooBooking AS T2 ON T2.ID_Booking = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         oaccAccount AS T3 ON T3.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         otrnTrnAccount AS T5 ON T5.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         prCode AS T7 ON T1.ID_RateCode = T7.ID_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         rmRoom AS T6 ON T6.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
```

Que me da como resultado la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera es saber si hay una forma en la que pueda calcular el número de días entre la fecha de llegada y la fecha de salida y luego mostrar el resultado en una columna adicional de mi consulta.

Por Ejemplo:

Fecha de Salida (2019-04-04) - Fecha de Entrada (2019-04-01) = 3

**Respecto a que podría ser duplicado en otra pregunta comento lo siguiente:
La otra pregunta se refiere a la cantidad de días dentro de dos fechas diferentes en una misma semana.
El problema que yo tengo es que se pueden dar muchos cambios en que las fechas incluso estén en diferentes meses, por lo que la solución de la otra pregunta no aplica para este tema.**

Comment: Intentaste restando ambas columnas? `T1.DepartureDate - T1.ArrivalDate as diferencia` o algo parecido...

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo comparar dos fechas y hacer un conteo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92875/c%c3%b3mo-comparar-dos-fechas-y-hacer-un-conteo)

Comment: Intenté algo así SELECT        (T1.DepartureDate) - (T1.ArrivalDate)
FROM obooGuest AS T1 pero no funcionó

Comment: Ah! Cierto! Sql server tiene una función, `datediff(intervalo, finicial, ffinal)`. Intervalo es en qué quieres que te devuelva el resultado (day, month, year), finicial es la fecha inicial, y ffinal la fecha final. Suerte!

Comment: Como comentario a tu edición: DATEDIFF te dará la diferencia entre dos fechas, sin importar si son dos fechas en la misma semana, o en el mismo año o en el mismo siglo. Depende de cómo uses DATEDIFF (el intervalo) para que te diga lo que quieres saber (si lo quieres en días, en semanas, en meses, etc) [Aquí te explican cómo funciona DATEDIFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo lo que necesitas es aplicar un DATEDIFF este te puede ayudar a lo que necesitas te agrego un ejemplo

```
DECLARE @FechadeSalida DATE ='2019-04-04'
DECLARE @FechadeEntrada DATE='2019-04-01'


SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@FechadeEntrada,@FechadeSalida)
```

y tu consulta quedaria algo como esto

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.ArrivalDate,T1.DepartureDate ) AS DiasBetween, T3.AccountNo AS Folio, T6.RoomNo AS Habitacion, T2.GuestTotal AS Huespedes, T7.Name AS Tarifa, T1.ID_SrcBusiness
FROM            obooGuest AS T1 INNER JOIN
                         obooBooking AS T2 ON T2.ID_Booking = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         oaccAccount AS T3 ON T3.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         otrnTrnAccount AS T5 ON T5.ID_Account = T1.ID_Guest INNER JOIN
                         prCode AS T7 ON T1.ID_RateCode = T7.ID_Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         rmRoom AS T6 ON T6.ID_Room = T1.ID_Room
```

Como información extra DATEDIFF no solo funciona para dias, en el primer parametro le puedes pasar lo que necesites dias,semanas,meses,años

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@FechadeEntrada,@FechadeSalida)
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,@FechadeEntrada,@FechadeSalida)
SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR,@FechadeEntrada,@FechadeSalida)
```

Aqui te anexo unos ejemplos 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bf289d8971d644f2eda06e3b065b0731

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, en efecto tu comentario me dio la solución,

Comment: De nada :D Saludos