# Tiempo transcurrido entre dos fechas en SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Tengo la tabla persona con estos datos:

```
 ID,
codigo_area,
codigoArea_FechaInicio
```

El campo **codigoArea_FechaInicio** es el que indica la fecha en que entra en validez ese campo, la tabla tiene activado el modo de versionado, que me deja un historico ante cualquier modificación.

Entonces mi pregunta es, cómo puedo hacer para saber el tiempo que pasó (en dias/años/minutos, lo que sea) entre que cambio del codigo de area 1 al 2

gracias!

Comment: Hola, @Nico. ¿Has intentado algo? Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda indicar en este tipo de preguntas, el tipo de dato de cada columna y unos datos de prueba.

Comment: @Alfabravo Hola, la idea era que me ayuden en el planteamiento del problema. No que me den una solución

Comment: Significa que es aún más importante revisar los enlaces que te compartí para que puedas plantear una pregunta que encaje en el formato del sitio. Con o sin buscar solución, sigue incompleta.

Comment: Ya buscaste la función DATEDIFF()?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Calcular el número de días entre dos fechas (SQL Server)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288266/calcular-el-n%c3%bamero-de-d%c3%adas-entre-dos-fechas-sql-server)

Comment: La diferencia en tiempos para un campo de una tabla versionada se extrae con FOR SYSTEM_TIME y luego en función de la subcláusula ya se puede operar. Pero para apoyarte, tienes que mejorar mucho tú escenario.  [FOR SYSTEM_TIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/querying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15)